# ManagedEvent with companion Event metadata

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, parsley

I'm trying to declare a customized ManagedEvent with ActionScript as follows:

> ```
> [Bindable]  
> [ManagedEvents(names="message")]
> public class ClassName extends EventDispatcher
> {
>   .........
>  }
> ```

The problem came when sonar impposed to have a companion Event with that ManagedEvents.

I added the following Event metadata :

> ```
> [Bindable]
> [Event(name="message",type="package.ClassEvent")]
> [ManagedEvents(names="message")]
> public class ClassName extends EventDispatcher
> {
>   ....    
>  }
> ```

But the problem still unsolved with sonar.

This is a link for sonar SonarAnalyzer for flex :
http://dist.sonarsource.com/reports/coverage/rules/flex_rules_coverage.html

where there is this rule : https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=flex%3AS1464

```
Each ManagedEvents metadata tag should have a companion Event metadata tag
```

I really need to fix this issue, have you an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by removing the names attribut in ManagedEvents:

```
[Bindable]
[Event(name="message",type="package.ClassEvent")]
[ManagedEvents("message")]
public class ClassName extends EventDispatcher
{
  ....    
 }
```